# OutofMemoryError ImageView

Tags: android, out-of-memory, viewflipper

I have a problem with imageview, i have 77 picture jpg and have 126 quote text, just simple app i want is i want show all quote with background picture and i use viewflipper so when i swipe left/right get into next quote. I give you my code that i use now. Hope that anyone can help me.. Really wasting my time to fix it. My picture : 320x480.

```
                    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.pages);
            for (i = 0; i<totalphrase;i++) {
                Log.i("ID",""+i);
                var = arrayphrase.get(i);

                //iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100), (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100), (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)));
                FrameLayout a = new FrameLayout(this);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
                a.setLayoutParams(lp);

                b = new ImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp2= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(740, 800,Gravity.CENTER);
                //b.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100), (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100), (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)));

   // i got outofmemoryerror with this, Imgid[] -> my picture in drawable there ara 77picture
    b.setBackgroundResource(Imgid[(int)(Math.random()*Imgid.length)]);
    // -- ERROR --  outofmemory             
                b.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                a.addView(b);

                c = new ScrollView(this);
                c.setLayoutParams(lp2);
                //c.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                c.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(65, 53, 52, 52));
                //idsc = c.getId();
                a.addView(c);

                LinearLayout d = new LinearLayout(this);
                d.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                //d.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background0);
                c.addView(d);


                TextView e = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(730, 800);
                e.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                e.setText(var.phraseKey);

                d.addView(e);


                vf.addView(a);

            }

        }
```

The result that i want like this : [example that i want to build in android](http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/7577/20120620163458.jpg)

and this is xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/fl1"
        >


        <ViewFlipper

            android:id="@+id/pages"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            android:layout_gravity="top"
            >
        </ViewFlipper>


    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Two words: Arrays, Thumbnails

Comment: i dont understand, can u explain me? im newbie in objective c like java android

Comment: could you please cut down the entire code and show only the required parts?

Comment: @AndroSelva ok i already cut the important thinks when i setpicture in for looping.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create an 2 dim array containing the comment and the path to the picture. 
For the pictures, create a thumbnail. I am doing it with this code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPicPath, options);
image.setImageBitmap(pic);
```

I am not sure if image gets smaller with bigger inSampleSize... You'll have to try

image is in XML:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
                android:layout_width="134dp"
                android:layout_height="146dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.36"
                android:onClick="imageClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use the on click method to open the image in the gallery but you can do zoom or what you want.

Comment: i didnt use onclick to see picture because background was random when i swipe right/left to the next quote text.

Answer (score 0):

To fix OutOfMemory you should do something like that:

this is a code i ref it's work good check it

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

This inSampleSize option reduces memory consumption.

Here's a complete method. First it reads image size without decoding the content itself. Then it finds the best inSampleSize value, it should be a power of 2. And finally the image is decoded.

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can u give me source code to do that, i still confuse where i must put in that code thx

Comment: ok no problem the error comes only when ur image file is not fit in ur image view so check ur image view and fix that it will be working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code before changing the image:

```
imageView.getDrawable().getBitmap().recycle();
```