# Am Getting OutOfMemoryError when trying to load images in my widget

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapimage

Hi am getting the following error, when i try to launch my widget, it a note taking app, this is the error I get, please kindly provide a workable answer using my code, would gladly accept the answer that works, thanks in advance:-

```
05-16 02:53:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(5335): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

and the error points to this line in my code:-

```
 File imgFile = new File(data.get(position).get("path"));
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
 imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250300/android-image-view-out-of-memory-error
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116913/outofmemoryerror-imageview

You should resize your image to a proper size.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to handle all this for you, which is highly recommended in my opinion. It's as simple as including the library and call this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(myBitmap).into(imageView);
```

Or, you can try the method outlined here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392972/how-to-load-large-images-in-android-and-avoiding-the-out-of-memory-error).

Specifically, this one.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, String resId, int    reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

 // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
 final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);

 // Calculate inSampleSize
 options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

 // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
 options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565; <---- the options and the one below are important
 options.inDither = true;
 return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resId, options);
 }
```

Comment: Try changing (context) to (getApplicationContext())

Comment: when i changed to (getApplicationContext()), i now get an error on .load

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone out there, after several hours without an answer to this. I found a way of handling the outOfMemoryError. I added this line of code in my Manifest file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

I added this to the entire application here as below:-

```
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:largeHeap="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

android:largeHeap is the instrument for increasing your allocated memory to app.